# Keycloak: Users are not imported from OpenLDAP

Tags: keycloak, openldap

In the Keycloak Users view I cannot see the LDAP users, although they should have been imported:

```
2023-08-17 08:01:27,607 INFO  [org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPIdentityStoreRegistry] (Timer-0) Creating new LDAP Store for the LDAP storage provider: 'ldap', LDAP Configuration: {pagination=[false], fullSyncPeriod=[3600], startTls=[false], usersDn=[ou=users,dc=vlch,dc=local], connectionPooling=[false], cachePolicy=[DEFAULT], useKerberosForPasswordAuthentication=[false], importEnabled=[true], enabled=[true], usernameLDAPAttribute=[uid], bindDn=[cn=admin,dc=vlch,dc=local], changedSyncPeriod=[600], vendor=[other], uuidLDAPAttribute=[entryUUID], allowKerberosAuthentication=[false], connectionUrl=[ldap://x.x.x.x:389], syncRegistrations=[true], authType=[simple], useTruststoreSpi=[always], usePasswordModifyExtendedOp=[false], trustEmail=[false], userObjectClasses=[*], rdnLDAPAttribute=[uid], editMode=[READ_ONLY], validatePasswordPolicy=[false]}, binaryAttributes: []
2023-08-17 08:01:27,619 INFO  [org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPStorageProviderFactory] (Timer-0) Sync changed users from LDAP to local store: realm: 644c2eae-8186-4cbb-96bc-03a146c4b62a, federation provider: ldap, last sync time: Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 1970
2023-08-17 08:01:27,980 INFO  [org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPStorageProviderFactory] (Timer-0) Sync changed users finished: 3 imported users, 0 updated users
```

When accessing the users via the REST API {{KEYCLOAK_HOST}}/admin/realms/{{realm}}/users I can see them:

```
[
    {
        "id": "2807a4c6-b947-48b1-97f2-111f25f3eff3",
        "createdTimestamp": 1692259287960,
        "username": "user01",
        "enabled": true,
        "totp": false,
        "emailVerified": false,
        "firstName": "User1",
        "lastName": "Bar1",
        "federationLink": "39637f5c-cf75-4f37-ba6b-8bb634190cfc",
        "attributes": {
            "LDAP_ENTRY_DN": [
                "cn=user01,ou=users,dc=vlch,dc=local"
            ],
            "modifyTimestamp": [
                "20230817073107Z"
            ],
            "createTimestamp": [
                "20230817073107Z"
            ],
            "LDAP_ID": [
                "c638e942-d11b-103d-87db-67ab5a774fb1"
            ]
        },
        "disableableCredentialTypes": [],
        "requiredActions": [],
        "notBefore": 0,
        "access": {
            "manageGroupMembership": true,
            "view": true,
            "mapRoles": true,
            "impersonate": true,
            "manage": true
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "f60bf9db-460a-41a0-841a-b181211592d4",
        "createdTimestamp": 1692259287968,
        "username": "user02",
        "enabled": true,
        "totp": false,
        "emailVerified": false,
        "firstName": "User2",
        "lastName": "Bar2",
        "federationLink": "39637f5c-cf75-4f37-ba6b-8bb634190cfc",
        "attributes": {
            "LDAP_ENTRY_DN": [
                "cn=user02,ou=users,dc=vlch,dc=local"
            ],
            "modifyTimestamp": [
                "20230817073107Z"
            ],
            "createTimestamp": [
                "20230817073107Z"
            ],
            "LDAP_ID": [
                "c639126e-d11b-103d-87dc-67ab5a774fb1"
            ]
        },
        "disableableCredentialTypes": [],
        "requiredActions": [],
        "notBefore": 0,
        "access": {
            "manageGroupMembership": true,
            "view": true,
            "mapRoles": true,
            "impersonate": true,
            "manage": true
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "1f6eb0cb-a54c-41dc-944c-ab840f308a66",
        "createdTimestamp": 1692259287972,
        "username": "user03",
        "enabled": true,
        "totp": false,
        "emailVerified": false,
        "firstName": "User3",
        "lastName": "Bar3",
        "federationLink": "39637f5c-cf75-4f37-ba6b-8bb634190cfc",
        "attributes": {
            "LDAP_ENTRY_DN": [
                "cn=user03,ou=users,dc=vlch,dc=local"
            ],
            "modifyTimestamp": [
                "20230817073107Z"
            ],
            "createTimestamp": [
                "20230817073107Z"
            ],
            "LDAP_ID": [
                "c6397fba-d11b-103d-87dd-67ab5a774fb1"
            ]
        },
        "disableableCredentialTypes": [],
        "requiredActions": [],
        "notBefore": 0,
        "access": {
            "manageGroupMembership": true,
            "view": true,
            "mapRoles": true,
            "impersonate": true,
            "manage": true
        }
    }
]
```

This is my LDAP user federation configuration:

```
{
  "pagination":[
    false
  ],
  "fullSyncPeriod":[
    3600
  ],
  "startTls":[
    false
  ],
  "usersDn":[
    "ou=users,dc=vlch,dc=local"
  ],
  "connectionPooling":[
    false
  ],
  "cachePolicy":[
    "DEFAULT"
  ],
  "useKerberosForPasswordAuthentication":[
    false
  ],
  "importEnabled":[
    true
  ],
  "enabled":[
    true
  ],
  "usernameLDAPAttribute":[
    "uid"
  ],
  "bindDn":[
    "cn=admin,dc=vlch,dc=local"
  ],
  "changedSyncPeriod":[
    600
  ],
  "vendor":[
    "other"
  ],
  "uuidLDAPAttribute":[
    "entryUUID"
  ],
  "allowKerberosAuthentication":[
    false
  ],
  "connectionUrl":[
    "ldap://x.x.x.x:389"
  ],
  "syncRegistrations":[
    true
  ],
  "authType":[
    "simple"
  ],
  "useTruststoreSpi":[
    "always"
  ],
  "usePasswordModifyExtendedOp":[
    false
  ],
  "trustEmail":[
    false
  ],
  "userObjectClasses":[
    "*"
  ],
  "rdnLDAPAttribute":[
    "uid"
  ],
  "editMode":[
    "READ_ONLY"
  ],
  "validatePasswordPolicy":[
    false
  ]
}
"binaryAttributes":[]
```

This is the ldapsearch output (normal):

```
# ldapsearch -v -H ldap://x.x.x.x:389 -x -b'dc=vlch,dc=local'
ldap_initialize( ldap://x.x.x.x:389/??base )
filter: (objectclass=*)
requesting: All userApplication attributes
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=vlch,dc=local> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# vlch.local
dn: dc=vlch,dc=local
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
dc: vlch
o: example

# users, vlch.local
dn: ou=users,dc=vlch,dc=local
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: users

# user01, users, vlch.local
dn: cn=user01,ou=users,dc=vlch,dc=local
cn: User1
cn: user01
sn: Bar1
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
userPassword:: cGFzc3dvcmQx
uid: user01
uidNumber: 1000
gidNumber: 1000
homeDirectory: /home/user01

# user02, users, vlch.local
dn: cn=user02,ou=users,dc=vlch,dc=local
cn: User2
cn: user02
sn: Bar2
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
userPassword:: cGFzc3dvcmQy
uid: user02
uidNumber: 1001
gidNumber: 1001
homeDirectory: /home/user02

# user03, users, vlch.local
dn: cn=user03,ou=users,dc=vlch,dc=local
cn: User3
cn: user03
sn: Bar3
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
userPassword:: U2llbWVucy0x
uid: user03
uidNumber: 1002
gidNumber: 1002
homeDirectory: /home/user03

# readers, groups, vlch.local
dn: cn=readers,ou=groups,dc=vlch,dc=local
objectClass: groupOfNames
member: cn=user02,ou=users,dc=vlch,dc=local
member: cn=user03,ou=users,dc=vlch,dc=local
member: cn=user01,ou=users,dc=vlch,dc=local
cn: readers

# groups, vlch.local
dn: ou=groups,dc=vlch,dc=local
ou: groups
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top

# main, groups, vlch.local
dn: cn=main,ou=groups,dc=vlch,dc=local
cn: main
member: cn=user03,ou=users,dc=vlch,dc=local
objectClass: groupOfNames
objectClass: top

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 9
# numEntries: 8
```

This is the ldapsearch output (with hidden attributes):

```
# ldapsearch -v -H ldap://x.x.x.x:389 -x -b'dc=vlch,dc=local' +
ldap_initialize( ldap://x.x.x.x:389/??base )
filter: (objectclass=*)
requesting: + 
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=vlch,dc=local> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: + 
#

# vlch.local
dn: dc=vlch,dc=local
structuralObjectClass: organization
entryUUID: c63893d4-d11b-103d-87d9-67ab5a774fb1
creatorsName: cn=admin,dc=vlch,dc=local
createTimestamp: 20230817073107Z
entryCSN: 20230817073107.426863Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=admin,dc=vlch,dc=local
modifyTimestamp: 20230817073107Z
entryDN: dc=vlch,dc=local
subschemaSubentry: cn=Subschema
hasSubordinates: TRUE

# users, vlch.local
dn: ou=users,dc=vlch,dc=local
structuralObjectClass: organizationalUnit
entryUUID: c638bec2-d11b-103d-87da-67ab5a774fb1
creatorsName: cn=admin,dc=vlch,dc=local
createTimestamp: 20230817073107Z
entryCSN: 20230817073107.427978Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=admin,dc=vlch,dc=local
modifyTimestamp: 20230817073107Z
entryDN: ou=users,dc=vlch,dc=local
subschemaSubentry: cn=Subschema
hasSubordinates: TRUE

# user01, users, vlch.local
dn: cn=user01,ou=users,dc=vlch,dc=local
structuralObjectClass: inetOrgPerson
entryUUID: c638e942-d11b-103d-87db-67ab5a774fb1
creatorsName: cn=admin,dc=vlch,dc=local
createTimestamp: 20230817073107Z
entryCSN: 20230817090623.828587Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=admin,dc=vlch,dc=local
modifyTimestamp: 20230817090623Z
entryDN: cn=user01,ou=users,dc=vlch,dc=local
subschemaSubentry: cn=Subschema
hasSubordinates: FALSE

# user02, users, vlch.local
dn: cn=user02,ou=users,dc=vlch,dc=local
structuralObjectClass: inetOrgPerson
entryUUID: c639126e-d11b-103d-87dc-67ab5a774fb1
creatorsName: cn=admin,dc=vlch,dc=local
createTimestamp: 20230817073107Z
entryCSN: 20230817073107.430120Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=admin,dc=vlch,dc=local
modifyTimestamp: 20230817073107Z
entryDN: cn=user02,ou=users,dc=vlch,dc=local
subschemaSubentry: cn=Subschema
hasSubordinates: FALSE

# user03, users, vlch.local
dn: cn=user03,ou=users,dc=vlch,dc=local
structuralObjectClass: inetOrgPerson
entryUUID: c6397fba-d11b-103d-87dd-67ab5a774fb1
creatorsName: cn=admin,dc=vlch,dc=local
createTimestamp: 20230817073107Z
entryCSN: 20230817073107.432918Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=admin,dc=vlch,dc=local
modifyTimestamp: 20230817073107Z
entryDN: cn=user03,ou=users,dc=vlch,dc=local
subschemaSubentry: cn=Subschema
hasSubordinates: FALSE

# readers, groups, vlch.local
dn: cn=readers,ou=groups,dc=vlch,dc=local
structuralObjectClass: groupOfNames
entryUUID: c639ab70-d11b-103d-87de-67ab5a774fb1
creatorsName: cn=admin,dc=vlch,dc=local
createTimestamp: 20230817073107Z
entryCSN: 20230817110936.059512Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=admin,dc=vlch,dc=local
modifyTimestamp: 20230817110936Z
entryDN: cn=readers,ou=groups,dc=vlch,dc=local
subschemaSubentry: cn=Subschema
hasSubordinates: FALSE

# groups, vlch.local
dn: ou=groups,dc=vlch,dc=local
structuralObjectClass: organizationalUnit
entryUUID: 251d5fc4-d13a-103d-9c67-2d90308da14c
creatorsName: cn=admin,dc=vlch,dc=local
createTimestamp: 20230817110831Z
entryCSN: 20230817110831.533698Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=admin,dc=vlch,dc=local
modifyTimestamp: 20230817110831Z
entryDN: ou=groups,dc=vlch,dc=local
subschemaSubentry: cn=Subschema
hasSubordinates: TRUE

# main, groups, vlch.local
dn: cn=main,ou=groups,dc=vlch,dc=local
structuralObjectClass: groupOfNames
entryUUID: 88c5e0a0-d13a-103d-9c68-2d90308da14c
creatorsName: cn=admin,dc=vlch,dc=local
createTimestamp: 20230817111118Z
entryCSN: 20230817111118.732779Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=admin,dc=vlch,dc=local
modifyTimestamp: 20230817111118Z
entryDN: cn=main,ou=groups,dc=vlch,dc=local
subschemaSubentry: cn=Subschema
hasSubordinates: FALSE

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 9
# numEntries: 8
```

I used the `bitnami/openldap:2.6` image for OpenLDAP and the `keycloak/keycloak:22.0` image for the Keycloak instance.
Since the log message `2023-08-17 08:01:27,980 INFO  [org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPStorageProviderFactory] (Timer-0) Sync changed users finished: 3 imported users, 0 updated users` was seen, I would expect that I can also see the imported users in the Users overview of the Realm, but they do not appear there.

Also when changing the `uuidLDAPAttribute` from `entryUUID` to `uid` the users are not imported.
Same behavior when changing the `first name` mapper `LDAP Attribute` from `cn` to `uid`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the search, once you have an LDAP provider, Keycloak does not seem to show all users by default anymore (for performance reasons, i suppose). You have to type something in the search or "*" for all.